# Securing PHP on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: php, security, ubuntu-12.04, apache-2.4

I recently set up an Ubuntu 12.04 server (with Apache 2.2 & PHP 5.3.10).  While I was testing it, I noticed in the Apache access logs that an unknown IP address was trying to perform a PHP CGI injection attack, exploiting a known flaw described here:

http://www.osvdb.org/81633

Luckily I happened to notice this and I prevented the intruder from gaining access to the server, but the injection attack *did* succeed in changing some of my php.ini settings.  According to the description of the vulnerability, the only versions of PHP immune to injection are 5.3.13 and 5.4.3+.  I tried to upgrade to 5.5 by using this (apparently popular) unofficial repository:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

It upgraded my PHP but it also destroyed my Apache settings and upgraded Apache to 2.4, which I can't use.  So I had to rollback the system.

I then tried to upgrade to PHP 5.3.13 using apt-get, but apparently 5.3.10 is the highest version available from the official Ubuntu 12.04 repos.  A little frustrating, to say the least.

So my question is: how can I secure PHP 3.5.10 or install a "safe" version of PHP on Ubuntu 12.04, so that I can prevent the re-occurrence of this kind of attack?  I definitely do NOT want Apache 2.4, and I need an LTS server.

Comment: Why can't you use Apache 2.4?

Comment: Because I'm using other software that requires 2.2 (it's just part of the job and there's nothing I can do about it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canonical back ports these fixes for Ubuntu.  The incident that you found was fixed in 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2.  It appears that the latest version is 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9.  You can [go back and look at the change logs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9) for the various releases.

I suggest that you keep your distro up to date.  These commands should do it.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you're brave, cron that.  If not, run it frequently to keep your system up to the latest patch level.